# Why do we treat a ball confined to a box as a series of problems in lagrangian mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Oliver Davis Johns in his book 'Analytical Mechanics for Relativity and Quantum Mechanics' states

> In Lagrangian mechanics, a ball confined to a box with perfectly elastic, rigid walls would be treated as a series of problems. Each problem would end when the ball hits a wall, the reflection conditions would be applied, and the next problem would begin with the resulting initial conditions.

I don't understand why we would need to do so.

Comment: What would you propose as an alternative? (This would help us see where the misunderstanding is)

Comment: I can't think of anything as an alternative. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't treat impulsive forces during collision, or provide a detailed description of the collision, the author proposes to split the description in a series of problems of smooth dynamics, separated by the collisions.

Using this approach, you need to:

- solve the smooth dynamics with no collision, governed by the principles of dynamics, namely (if we can treat the ball as a point mass):

  $m \ddot{\mathbf{r}} = \mathbf{f} \qquad$ for $t \in [t_{i-1}, t_i]$
- integrate the dynamics, find the time when the $i^{th}$ collision occurs, and the position and velocity just before the collision, $\mathbf{r}_i$, $\mathbf{v}^-_i$
- use the conditions that describe the collision, to get the velocity at just after the $i^{th}$ collision. For an elastic collision on a rigid and steady wall, the kinetic energy is conserved, as well as the momentum parallel to the wall. The velocity after the collision reads:

  $\mathbf{v}_i^+ = \mathbf{v}_i^- - 2 ( \mathbf{v}_i^- \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}) \mathbf{\hat{n}}$,

  so that:

  - the normal component: $\mathbf{v}_i^+ \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = -\mathbf{v}_i^- \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}$,
  - the tangential component: $\mathbf{v}_i^+ - ( \mathbf{v}_i^+ \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}) \mathbf{\hat{n}} = \mathbf{v}_i^- - ( \mathbf{v}_i^- \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}) \mathbf{\hat{n}}$

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the context, but if I hazard a guess:
the author is of the opinion that in the context of Lagrangian mechanics each bounce is effectively a standalone event.

Compare the case of the swing of a pendulum.
In the case of pendulum swing the pendulum bob is subject to a force *continuously*. So there is complete *continuity*.

For a bouncing scenario let me simplify to the following type of classroom demonstration: a linear [air track](https://physlab.org/experiment/experiments-with-a-linear-air-track/)

The glider moves along the air track, and at the ends there is a setup such that the glider is bounced back, for instance a coiled spring.

With that air track scenario the force is discontinuous. The amount of force exerted by the coiled spring is in *response* to being deformed by the glider bumping into it.

In order to apply Lagrangian mechanics you need an expression for potential energy, and potential energy is defined as the negative of [work done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_(physics)). Work done is the integral of force over distance.

Lagrangian mechanics is applicable when there is a well defined potential energy.

With the air track and the glider: there is a transition:
During transit: no force is being exerted on the glider.
When the glider comes into contact with the spring the spring starts exerting force.

For applying Lagrangian mechanics you don't want to have that kind of discontinuity; if there is a force you want it to be *always present*, so that you can obtain a well defined potential. (For integration you can have a force that at great distance diminishes ever closer to zero; that will not prevent you from obtaining a well defined potential.)

So I'm guessing that David Johns is of the opinion that Lagrangian mechanics will not accommodate discontituity. Instead the motion has to be divided in subsections, with no discontinuity within each subsection.